# How can resume file transfer in WinSCP from where it is broken

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, winscp

i am put command to upload files FTP server and each file like 3-5GB in size. Sometime server is disconnecting in between file transfer and when it reconnects it starts from broken file but it starts as fresh file. Example, if my download completes 99% then it disconnected and it is starting from the beginning of file.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /log="D:\new\winscp_log\winscp_%yymmdd_hhmmss%.log" -rawtransfersettings PreserveTimeDirs=1 /command ^
    "option batch abort" ^
    "open ftps://***%%2Fsupport@***.com:%Password%@***.sharefileftp.com -hostkey="**"  -rawsettings SendBuf=0 SshSimple=0 FtpPingType=0 -passive=on" ^
    "put E:\MDR2\FILE_BACKUP /MDR2/FILE_BACKUP -neweronly -speed=0 -resumesupport=on" ^
    "exit"
```

[image]

Comment: WinSCP should resume on it own with the default settings. If it does not, there something that prevents it from doing so. Post a session log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl log file is copied. Even -resume not working

Comment: Why are you trying to add the log to the answer? Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the put command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) shows that there's a `-resume` option that is valid as long as you are using SFTP or FTP.

```
put E:\MDR2\FILE_BACKUP /MDR2/FILE_BACKUP -resume -neweronly -speed=0 -resumesupport=on
```